# Equivalent to Me.Value for LinearGauge

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to make Color property dependent on the Gauge's value without having to copy and paste the expression. With a TextBox it's just `Me.Value` but it doesn't work that way on a gauge apparently. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Me.Value doesn't work on any SSRS chart expression.

Instead, I use CASE statements in the SQL dataset to create generic columns e.g. for the gauge value.  This has a side benefit of being easier to test/debug.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I am working on a Dynamics CRM DataSource (based on proprietary FetchXml) so no SQL = no joy! Thank you anyway

Comment: Oh dear.  You might try adding a calculated column to your dataset definition then.  You can use the Switch function as a proxy for SQL's CASE statement.  Its a bit obscure, but probably better than copying a complex expression into multiple obscure spots.  Good luck!